# Upside down question marks when printing characters from a 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, character

I have a 2d array that is a prototype "map" for a game I am making. It takes in the length of the map and width of the map, and then the type of character to make the map (either a - _ or .) and prints the character X by Y times.

For some reason whenever my grid X and Y do not equal each other and are of a value of about 20 or higher, I get upside down question marks instead of the character symbol I am specifying.

Why is this so?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int Y=25;
int X=15;
char map[Y][X];

int i,j=0;

for (i=0;i<Y;i++)
    for(j=0;j<X;j++)
        map[Y][X]='-'//any character;


for (i=0;i<Y;i++){
    for(j=0;j<X;j++){
        printf("%c",map[Y][X]);}
    printf("\n");}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: the array is uninitialized - only writing one element at `map[25][15]`, which is actually outside your bounds

Comment: You may want to actually use those indices rather than just counting with them. I.e. `map[i][j]`, not `map[Y][X]`. Doing so has the added benefit of removing the undefined behavior your program currently exhibits by exceeding the declared array boundaries.

Comment: thanks, I fixed it by adding a -1 to every X and Y in the map brackets

Comment: You'll have to trust me when I say, "fixed it" is a relative term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, subtracting one from X and Y isn't the point.  You are increment i and j. Use *them*.  Consider making X & Y const.

```
int Y = 25;
int X = 15;
char map[Y][X];

int i, j = 0;

for (i = 0;i < Y;i++)
    for (j = 0;j < X;j++)
        map[i][j] = '-';  //any character

for (i = 0;i < Y;i++)
{
    for (j = 0;j < X;j++)
    {
        printf("%c", map[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

return (0);
```

Comment: oh ok, now that I think about it, thats obviously. Cant believe I didnt realize that. Thank you!